# How to correctly "bypass" Angular Sanitization?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an `input type=text` where my user will type his own HTML template.
I have a button that opens a modal which shows the formatted html as a *"preview html template"*.

Whenever the user Clicks on my *preview_button*, it opens a modal that shows the html the user typed before. This is part of the modal, this is how I'm inserting the html:

```
<div class="flexBox mg-2">
  <span [innerHTML]="my.element.text"></span>
</div>
```

Although it is working and showing the text correctly. It doesn't allow me to use `style` formatting. So If my user write this on the *text_input*

`<h1 style="color:red;">Hello World</h1>`

When the modal opens, I can see the text but not the color styling.

I found a few topics here suggesting to use  `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml`, but I also read its kind of dangerous and also it messes all my pages style up, so I can't use it.
And a few examples showing how to do this with a static html(on class constructor).

### Edit

Tried to use `iframe`.
It works like this(inline css):

```
<iframe srcdoc="'<h1 style='color:red;'>Hello World</h1>'"></iframe>
```

Also works like this(style tag):

```
<iframe srcdoc="<h1 id='pp'>Hello World</h1><style>#pp{color:red;}</style>"></iframe>
```

**BUT** when I try to use `interpolation` it no longer applies the style. (due to the *Angular Policy*)

```
<iframe [srcdoc]="components.body.text"></iframe>
```

Any good/correct/safe way to do it when the html is **dynamic**?

Comment: *I also read its kind of dangerous* - `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` is no more dangerous than other methods of letting user write html

Comment: *also it messes all my pages style up* - weird, it shouldn't happen

Comment: for some reason, when I use the `byPassHtml` and/or `byPassStyle` the whole css of my pages are deconfigurated

Comment: Works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-turing-ydtosn?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Konrad You are 100% right. It worked! Not sure why but I tried `this.sanitizer.byPass...` totally forgot about the DomSanitizer that I read before. Thank you! Any drawback using this only for this specific situation?

Comment: If you won't save it to the database then no. But if you would, you are allowing xss attacks. Simple string like `<img src="" onerror="alert(1)">` will allow executing any javascript

Comment: Yeah, I'm just using it to display a html template with css to user. Perfect then.  Thanks dude. Add this as an answer if you like so I can accept it.  I need to read more about it and understand what I did wrong before with the bypass.